# How can I know if my app's camera permission is granted?

Tags: android

I want to know if my app's camera permission is granted or not. Then I written the below functions, but they are always return incorrect result. Not matter how can I disabled the camera permission of my app in system settings, the both functions always return TRUE. Do you know something wrong in my codes?

```
public static boolean checkCameraPermission() {
    String permission = "android.permission.CAMERA";
    int res = App.getInstance().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
    return (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}

public static boolean checkCameraPermission(Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    boolean permission = (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ==
            pm.checkPermission("android.permission.CAMERA", pm.getNameForUid(Binder.getCallingUid())));
    return permission;
}
```

Comment: What version of Android are you running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to know if my app's camera permission is granted or not

If your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, and you are running on an Android 6.0+ device, use `checkSelfPermission()`. The native implementation of `checkSelfPermission()` is on `Context`; `ContextCompat` has a version that will not crash on older Android devices.

If your `targetSdkVersion` is 22 or lower, or you are running on an Android 5.1 or older device, you always have your requested permissions (exception: possibly some custom ROMs).

If your `targetSdkVersion` is 22 or lower, and you are running on an Android 6.0 or higher device, you also always have your requested permissions, in terms of the methods that you are calling as outlined in your question. The user, in Settings, can block your access to data associated with those permissions, but technically the user is not actually revoking the permissions themselves (though we often say they are just to keep the explanation simple). I know of no way for you to determine that the user is blocking your camera access, other than by catching the relevant exceptions when you attempt to access the camera. Note that those exceptions will be raised in other scenarios (e.g., camera access is blocked by device policy).