# Android check camera permission in target sdk 22 or lower

Tags: android

I have my code like this to check camera permission.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
Log.e("Permission State",ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)+"");

// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
showCameraActivityForResult(activity);
}else {
// No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, Constant.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
}
}else{
showCameraActivityForResult(activity);
}
```

Problem is that I always have permission granted in 5.1 or lower. Other user also said here.

[How can I know if my app's camera permission is granted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33920254/how-can-i-know-if-my-apps-camera-permission-is-granted)

In some device like samsung, user can disable camera permission from device setting and as a result, when user open my app and tap on camera, it always show blank. How can I detect whether user can use camera? (it need to be different from my code since it is not working.)

Comment: you don't require to check any permission below Lolipop(22) OS as permission change on runtime introduced in Lolipop.

Comment: Permission is granted at the first time (default behavior for 22 and below) but user disable it later from device setting in samsung device. How shall I do?

Answer (score 4):

If you use AppCompatActivity, you can use `checkSelfPermission` to check if permission have been granted.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

      //Show permission dialog
     } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, code);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to check for below api 22. How can I check? For below 22, I can't use checkSelfPermission. I need a way to know that camera can't be used due to user restriction or something.

Comment: Yes, checkSelfPermission is not available for api below than 22. Because you don't need to check for it. You just need to declare the permission in manifest, and user will grant the permission during installation. If you see some devices have feature to disable/enable permission on device settings, probably that device run on Android > 23. You can refer to here: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Permission is granted at the first time (default behavior for 22 and below) but user disable it later from device setting in samsung device. How shall I handle for that case? May b is there some kind of checking exception?

Comment: Can you re-verify what is the android version running on that samsung device? As far as I know, only android > 23 (Marshmallow and above) has capability to enable and disable the permission on settings. If the app is running on android > 23, you can safely use above method to check for the permission. You should not be worried about api < 23 at all. Once granted, it always granted and user cannot disable it even later.

Comment: omm... I am sorry. Device is android version 6.0.1, api 23 . But I use yours and it is still granted.

Answer (score 1):

On API 22 and below permissions are granted if specified in the manifest.

For API 23+ [`ContextCompat#checkSelfPermission`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) could be of use. It "degrades" gracefully on earlier APIs and will tell you the permission is granted if it appears in the manifest. On API 23 and above it will actually check if it's granted.

It returns [PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#PERMISSION_GRANTED) if the permission is granted.

call it in an `Activity` with [Manifest.permission.CAMERA](http://[Manifest.permission.CAMERA][3]) to avoid typos.

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA));
```

Comment: I need to check for below api 22. How can I check? For below 22, I can't use checkSelfPermission. I need a way to know that camera can't be used due to user restriction or something.

Comment: The user can't restrict permissions in 22 and below. If they don't want to give your app permission, their only choice is to not install the app.

Comment: I have samsung device and in the device setting, user can manually disable camera permission to my app. :(

Comment: Permission is granted at the first time (default behavior for 22 and below) but user disable it later from device setting in samsung device.

Comment: Sorry. Let me modify my comment. Device is android version 6.0.1, api 23 . But I use yours and it is still granted.

Comment: `if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) == PERMISSION_GRANTED) { /*permission is granted* } else { /* denied */ }`
Check for permission just before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this,

private Context mContext=YourActivity.this;

private static final int REQUEST = 112;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
    if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST );
    } else {
        showCameraActivityForResult(activity);
    }
} else {
     showCameraActivityForResult(activity);
}
```

get Permissions Result

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                showCameraActivityForResult(activity);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to write in your storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

check permissions  for marshmallow

```
private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

OR :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) 
{
    Log.e("Permission State",ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)+"");

    // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        showCameraActivityForResult(activity);
    }
    else {
        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, Constant.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }
}else{
    showCameraActivityForResult(activity);
}
```

Comment: I need to check for below api 22. How can I check? For below 22, I can't use checkSelfPermission. I need a way to know that camera can't be used due to user restriction or something.

Comment: No need to check the permission for below 22, only add your permission in manifest file

Comment: Permission is granted at the first time (default behavior for 22 and below) but user disable it later from device setting in samsung device. How shall I handle for that case? May b is there some kind of checking exception?

Comment: Sorry. Let me modify my comment. Device is android version 6.0.1, api 23 . But I use yours and it is still granted.

Comment: use android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA

Answer (score 0):

checkSelfPermission is available above sdk 23.

we can check the permission is available or not using package manager

```
public static Boolean checkpermissions(Activity activity) {
  PackageManager mPackageManager = activity.getPackageManager();
  int hasPermStorage = mPackageManager.checkPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA, activity.getPackageName());

  if (hasPermStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // do stuff
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return false;
  } else if (hasPermStorage == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // do stuff
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Has permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
  } else {
     return false;
  }
```